# An error occured when i converted a java project to maven project for selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven

I am facing an issue. Mine issue is that when i created a java project in Eclipse IDE its all good no errors but when i converted it to a maven project as i wanted to work with selenium, it shows me error i tried to troubleshoot but i didn't succeeded.
I hope all will help me.
A screen shot of the issue is provided.

I converted a java project to maven and after converting it shows error.
I expected that it will not show any error.

[image]

Comment: Do a maven clean and build and then check if issue still persists.

Comment: What are the full error messages?